# Reinstalling macOS High Sierra from Recovery Tools takes many hours on 2016/2017 MacBook Pros

Tags: macbook-pro, install, high-sierra

I have recently purchased two new MacBook Pros. One is a 2016 13" MacBook Pro, the other a 2017 15" MacBook Pro. On both of them, I have had to reinstall macOS High Sierra from the Recovery Tools. On both machines, it has taken over 5 hours to install.

These aren't the low-end Mac Pros, these are the maxed-out config-to-order, with upgraded processors, drives, and RAM. So it is unfathomable that it would take so long to install macOS High Sierra.

I am currently waiting for the 15" MacBook Pro to install High Sierra going on 6 hours now. The progress bar does move, but ever so slightly. The "time remaining" is always 1 hour +/- 30 or so minutes, but obviously that isn't accurate.

Since posting this question, macOS is still sitting at 52 minutes remaining for the last hour. The progress bar has not moved a pixel.

It is normal for macOS High Sierra to install this slowly on these machines? If not, what can I do to reinstall the software more quickly?

Answer (score 2):

The one thing that I would say is that Apple has changed the recovery process somewhat in 10.13 High Sierra. Newer model Mac computers now have to pull down much more from Apple's side.

What sort of internet connection are you on. 5 - 6 hours does sound pretty extreme but 2 - 3 hours I have seen in our lab at work for sure!

Comment: Yes, I think the download speed is or could be a large part of this - especially if one is watching a video while the downloads are happening...

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a Mac up and running, goto the App Store and download High Sierra. This will download as an application. You can then transfer this application to a bootable USB flash drive. Booting and installing High Sierra from a flash drive is much faster and does not require any internet downloads. I would suggest using a USB 3 compatible flash drive, but USB 2 will also work. The instructions for making the USB flash drive installer can be found at the Apple website: [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).